# Creating a new Data.Frame from variable values

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently working on a task that requires me to query a list of stocks from an sql db.
The problem is that it is a list where there are 1:n stocks traded per date. I want to calculate the the share of each stock int he portfolio on a given day (see example) and pass it to a new data frame. In other words date x occurs 2 times (once for stock A and once for stock B) and then pull it together that date x occurs only one time with the new values.

```
'data.frame':   1010 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Date      : Date, format: "2019-11-22" "2019-11-21" "2019-11-20" "2019-11-19" ...
 $ Close: num  52 51 50.1 50.2 50.2 ...
 $ Volume     : num  5415 6196 3800 4784 6189 ...
 $ Stock_ID  : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

RawInput<-data.frame(Date=c("2017-22-11","2017-22-12","2017-22-13","2017-22-11","2017-22-12","2017-22-13","2017-22-11"), Close=c(50,55,56,10,11,12,200),Volume=c(100,110,150,60,70,80,30),Stock_ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3))
RawInput$Stock_ID<-as.factor(RawInput$Stock_ID)
```

*cannot transfer the date to a date variable in this example

I would like to have a new dataframe that generates the Value traded per day, the weight of each stock, and the daily returns per day, while keeping the number of stocks variable.

I hope I translated the issue properly so that I can receive help.

Thank you!

Comment: Providing a snipped of your data via `dput(head(df, 20))` would make it significantly easier for people to help you. Where `df` is your `data.frame`.

Comment: What `Date` should `2017-22-13` be?

Comment: `> dput(head(RawInput))
structure(list(ID = 1:6, Date = structure(c(18222, 18221, 18220, 
18219, 18218, 18215), class = "Date"), Close = c(52.03, 
51.03, 50.1, 50.16, 50.23, 50.68), Volume = c(5415, 6196, 3800, 
4784, 6189, 7753), Stock_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: -And the date is of course meant to be `2017-12-23` or something comparable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use the `dplyr` package. You may need to read some documentation but the `mutate` and `group_by` function may be able do what you want. This function will allow you to modify the current dataframe by either adding a new column or changing the existing data.

Lets start with a reproducible dataset

```
RawInput<-data.frame(Date=c("2017-22-11","2017-22-12","2017-22-13","2017-22-11","2017-22-12","2017-22-13","2017-22-11"),
                    Close=c(50,55,56,10,11,12,200),
                    Volume=c(100,110,150,60,70,80,30),
                    Stock_ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3))
RawInput$Stock_ID<-as.factor(RawInput$Stock_ID)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
dat2 <- RawInput %>%
    group_by(Date, Stock_ID) %>%  #this example only has one stock type but i imagine you want to group by stock
    mutate(CloseMean=mean(Close),
           CloseSum=sum(Close),
           VolumeMean=mean(Volume),
           VolumeSum=sum(Volume)) #what ever computation you need to do with
                                  #multiple stock values for a given date goes here
dat2 %>% select(Stock_ID, Date, CloseMean, CloseSum, VolumeMean,VolumeSum) %>% distinct() #dat2 will still be the same size as dat, thus use the distinct() function to reduce it to unique values
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   Date, Stock_ID [7]
  Stock_ID Date       CloseMean CloseSum VolumeMean VolumeSum
  <fct>    <fct>          <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1        2017-22-11        50       50        100       100
2 1        2017-22-12        55       55        110       110
3 1        2017-22-13        56       56        150       150
4 2        2017-22-11        10       10         60        60
5 2        2017-22-12        11       11         70        70
6 2        2017-22-13        12       12         80        80
7 3        2017-22-11       200      200         30        30
```

This data set that you provided actually only has one unique Stock_ID and Date combinations so there was nothing actually done with the data. However if you remove `Stock_ID` where necessary you can see how this function would work

```
dat2 <- RawInput %>%
        group_by(Date) %>%  
        mutate(CloseMean=mean(Close),
               CloseSum=sum(Close),
               VolumeMean=mean(Volume),
               VolumeSum=sum(Volume)) 
dat2 %>% select(Date, CloseMean, CloseSum, VolumeMean,VolumeSum) %>% distinct() 

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Date [3]
  Date       CloseMean CloseSum VolumeMean VolumeSum
  <fct>          <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2017-22-11      86.7      260       63.3       190
2 2017-22-12      33         66       90         180
3 2017-22-13      34         68      115         230
```

After reading your first reply, You will have to be specific on how you are trying to calculate the weight. Also define your end result.
Im going to assume weight is just percentage by total cost. And the end result is for each date show the weight per stock. In other words a matrix of dates and stock Ids

```
library(tidyr)
RawInput %>%
     group_by(Date) %>%
     mutate(weight=Close/sum(Close)) %>%
     select(Date, weight, Stock_ID) %>%
     spread(key = "Stock_ID", value = "weight", fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Date [3]
  Date         `1`    `2`   `3`
  <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 2017-22-11 0.192 0.0385 0.769
2 2017-22-12 0.833 0.167  0    
3 2017-22-13 0.824 0.176  0
```

Comment: Actually the result you presented at last is kind of where this should be eventually. Still the hurdle I want to take is that I want to assign the unique date (like in your last table) a Portfolio dataframe, that contains the weight of each stock in the portfolio (for the first 2 days weight of stock 3 would be 0). These weights could translate to a weighted portfolio value on a given day. So if there is a long list from the database that has 1 stock on 1 day and 3 stocks on a 2nd day then I want to be able to filter that information and keep it flexible so to say. Thank you very much!

Comment: It sounds like you will need to write a function if you are looking for a custom summary tool. Good luck with your endeavor

Comment: Thank you very much you answered the question